# Synonyms for three usages of "lazy"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

In normal usage, people consider "lazy" to have negative connotation. I hear people use "lazy" to mean three things.

1. Preferring not to do unnecessary things
2. Delaying necessary things until they absolutely require attention
3. Not wanting to do anything, even if necessary

In computer science, we often use "lazy" with the second meaning and we use it in a positive connotation.

Are there words which succinctly differentiate these three situations?

Comment: Are you looking for 1-Efficienct, 2-Procrastinating, and 3-Obstructionist?

Comment: There are many, many synonyms for lazy that capture various aspects and connotations. Have you looked at a thesaurus? Can you tell us which words come close and why they don't quite work for you? In addition to the existing suggestions I could suggest 1. Low-energy, 2. Dilatory, 3. Slothful...or 1. Economical, 2. Just-in-time, 3. Content. Without more to go on, probably someone else could suggest a completely different set that would also be equally valid.

Comment: Thank you, and great job finding positive and negative connotations for each!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first definition, *lazy* isn't the first word that springs to mind. In fact a near antonym  of lazy -- *focussed* -- fits the definition in the sense of not straying from the necessary task.

In the second case  I suggest  *procrastinatory* rather than *procrastinating* (from the comments and also valid), but this is negative  -- and in normal use for people it's hard to see how a synonym  wouldn't be negative, so you might struggle for a single word here

3 could be *lethargic* for a passive reluctance to act, or *obstructive* for an active refusal.

I'm not very familiar with the  CS uses of *lazy* -- the main example that I can think of is lazy matching in regular expressions, where it's used as an antonym for *greedy*, so closer to your first definition than your second. Some half-remembered references to algorithms  would fit this meaning better than number 2 as well .

Comment: "Postpone" might be a synonym for your second meaning.

Comment: @Xanne but there's no common adjective derived from *postpone*, and the question appears to be looking for an adjective

Comment: Thank you. FYI, the most common CS use of *lazy* relates collections of things. You could ask the computer "make a list of numbers from 1 to 1000". Normally it would allocate space for all thousand numbers and then retrieve from that list when you need it. A lazy sequence instead would only calculate each item when you try to retrieve it.

Comment: These are much better words to use, along with just-in-time above.

Comment: Now you remind me I recall seeing that use in Python  documentation  - but as most of my code is in the form of little scripts, it's a detail I don't often have to consider (just occasionally I apply code to much larger datasets than I wrote it for, then I have to optimise and pay attention to this sort of thing)

Comment: @Full Decent A lazy function or routine runs, then, on demand.